How can a data warehouse like BigQuery parallelize queries that Postgres cannot?
In order to get more practice with database management and reporting tools, I have been working to load the recent SSN data leak into Postgres. Since it is such a large dataset, it has served as a really good learning opportunity so far.
The dataset is a csv file that is formatted slightly incorrectly. I decided the best route forward was to import each line as a string and use some basic regex to extract the columns. I ran a query in postgres to extract a single column from the dataset with my regex, and it took more than 12 hours to run on an M3 Max. I didn't let it complete, so I don't know how long it would have actually taken. I did some research and did what I could find to optimize postgres for large database modifications, including writing to a new table instead of editing in place, and removing all indexes. These operations always ran on a single thread. From what I found in my research, if the postgres query planner can run a query on multiple threads it will, but most queries cannot be parallelized in this way.
Then I tried another method for cleaning the data: BigQuery. It took some time to get the dataset into GCP Storage, but once I did, it was incredibly fast. The total time for BigQuery to load 350GB of csv, run 12 different regular expressions against each, and output that to a new csv was about 10 minutes.
Here is my question: How can BigQuery complete the same query so much faster than postgres? What is architecturally different about a data warehouse that allows it to parallelize workflows that postgres cannot? Why doesn't postgres apply these lessons and parallelize their own queries?
Edit: Are there any projects that allow me to run a data warehouse like database locally? Or are they all tied to proprietary clouds like BigQuery/Snowflake/etc?

Perhaps this will help explain https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/bigquery/bigquery-under-the-hood

Running a DWH-like database locally: MariaDB ColumnStore. Vettabase has a documentation project for the community edition here. I think Postgres also has a columnar extension, but no idea how mature it is.

SQL Server also offers columnstore, @dbdemon.

@J.D. My bad - didn't see edit! Comment deleted!

Impossible to answer since you didn't share data, the data model, your query, your configuration, etc. Nobody knows what you tried. 350GB of data is not that much, and an M3 Max is a pretty fast machine. Most likely, you did something wrong. But that is just an assumption.
